# Adding Color to UITabBar - Very very Weird Bug?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uicolor

So,

I am subclassing my `UITabBarController` and I add the color Green to my `UITabBar`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 48);
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [v setAlpha:0.35];
    [[self tabBar] insertSubview:v atIndex:0];
    [v release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

This does not work .

But if I try `[[self tabBar] insertSubview:v atIndex:1];` it Works .. and a green color is added to the entire TabBar !!

I work on the iPhone Simulator using `ios5 SDK` and it works properly and I am able to select all tabs.
But when I try this code on the ios4.2 (real iPhone), **the first tab is visible.. but DOES NOT RESPOND TO TOUCH**

The reasons is clear, its because of adding a `SubView` of `greenColor` @ index ==1;

But If I change to `[[self tabBar] insertSubview:v atIndex:0];` my firstTab is selectable, but the `tabBar` just does not turn Green !!

Kindly Advise !!

Thanks.

---

**Edit:**

So the problem is associated with the iOS5 and the earlier versions. I will edit the answer and put back the original answer once iOS 5 is released.

Right now.... Off to the developer forums !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a custom control for this that does not subclass UITabBarController. From the documentation, "You should never access the tab bar view of a tab bar controller directly."

The view layers and the hierarchy part of the non-public API and subject to change across different version of the iOS.